# How can I solve this problem of connecting MySQL with Django

Tags: mysql, django, python-3.x, backend, web-development-server

This is the issue from running the server:

[image: This is the issue from running the server screenshot]

Comment: Are you able to connect to mysql in a separate command from the terminal?  [mysql -u root -p]

Comment: No, it is not possible. I have this message : ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2 "No such file or directory")

Comment: Try starting MySQL in Safe mode once as suggested here - https://serverfault.com/questions/706166/mysql-doesnt-start-mysqld-sock-is-missing

Comment: It still doesn't work. The issue is that I think the \'/var/run/mysqld/mysql.sock\' doesn't exit at all.